# Is there an example of a Baer ring $R$ for which $R/J(R)$ is not Baer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As the title suggests, I'm curious if there is an example of a Baer ring $R$ such that the quotient ring of $R$ by its Jacobson radical, i.e. $R/J(R)$, is not Baer.

By "Baer ring" I mean a ring $R$ with identity such that the right annihilator of any nonempty subset $X\subseteq R$ is generated by an idempotent of $R$. That is, for any nonempty $X\subseteq R$ there exists $e=e^2\in R$ such that $\{a\in R\mid Xa=0\}=eR$.

Comment: If there is such example, it shouldn't be very trivial since for the most standard examples of Baer rings: integral domains and semisimple rings, $R/J(R)$ is Baer..

Comment: Good question.  [Here are some possibilities](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=7&L=24&L=6) from the DaRT. The original search was for Baer, nonsemilocal, nonsemiprimitive rings, but there were no confirmed hits, only consistent hits. This means they have not been totally confirmed to fit the criterion, but are not eliminated either.  Even if one does fit the criteria completely, $R/J(R)$ may still be Baer.  I am very interested to see what transpires for this question.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for maintaining DaRT, it's really useful. As I'm working through the consistent hits for that search, I have found some determinations for some of the unknown properties of the rings in the database. Is there a way I can contribute those?

Comment: @SeaRyan Yes! That would be great!  If you register, there is a submission form.  All help like that is welcome, because there is too much for any single person to work on at any given time.

Comment: @SeaRyan The "Contribute" menu item is where it's at, if that is too hidden.